# Django Formset Errors With Input Name

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to get formset errors corresponding to its input name. Here I am using ajax to send the form data.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   category = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

forms.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model=Category
     field ="__all__"

CategoryFormset = modelformset_factory(Category, CategoryForm, , min_num=2, extra=0)
```

when i submit the form, i got the errors like this

python shell

```
formset.errors
[{'category': [u'This field is required.']}, {'category': [u'This field is required.']}]
```

But in my templates input name is different `form-0-category` and `form-1-category`. So is it possible to get errors something like this:
`[{'form-0-category': [u'This field is required.']}, {'form-1-category': [u'This field is required.']}]`. 
Somebody please help me.

templates

```
<p>
    <input id="id_form-0-category" maxlength="128" name="form-0-category" type="text"/>
 </p>

<p>
    <input id="id_form-1-category" maxlength="128" name="form-1-category" type="text" />
</p>
```

Comment: Could you please include the code where you perform the validation of that formset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't provide the list of errors in the format you want, but you can generate it yourself:

```
prefixed_errors = [{'%s-%s-%s' % (formset.prefix, index, k): v for k,v in errors.items()}
                   for (index, errors) in enumerate(formset.errors)]
```

This generates a list of dictionaries as in your question. I think you might want a single dictionary, which you could get with:

```
errors_dict = {'%s-%s-%s' % (formset.prefix, index, k): v for (index, errors) in enumerate(formset.errors) for k,v in errors.items()}
```

Comment: @Alasdair, seems like you have a misprint in your answer. One to mention, it should be `formset.errors` instead of `formset_errors`. But it doesn't work after this amendment either :(

Comment: Yes, the second example should be `formset.prefix` and `formset.errors`. With those changes it works for me.